# getting type mismatch while trying to retrieve object in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

When i try to retrieve an object in hibernate, it is throwing type mismatch exception.

`HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is` `org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class` `com.ecommerce.models.User. Expected: class com.ecommerce.models.User, got class` `java.lang.Integer`

```
Session session=getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx;
        tx=session.beginTransaction();
        User u1=new User();
        u1.setUserName("abcdef");
        u1.setPassword("abcdef");
        u1.setEmailId("abcdef");
        session.save(u1);
        tx.commit();

        User u=(User)session.get(User.class,u1.getId()); -->this line is throwing error
```

Class User is

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User implements Serializable {

@Id
@GenericGenerator(name="gen",strategy="increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
@NotNull
int Id;

@Id
@Column(name="USERNAME")
@NotEmpty
String userName;
@Id
@Column(name="EMAIL_ID")
@NotEmpty
String emailId;

@Column(name="PASSWORD")
@NotEmpty
String password;

Seetters and getters.....

}
```

Could anyone please help?

Comment: You already have it in `u1` since session is intact.

Comment: Yea, i created u1 for trial and error. I think the issue is occuring because i have declared more than one primary key in my table. Could anyone advise how can i use multiple primary key and using the same retrieval feature?

Comment: if you use more than one column as primary key, you'll have to use composite key in hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

You have three fields annotated with @Id,. If you are using a surrogate auto generated key then remove the @Id from email and username. Otherwise, if you are using email and username as a composite PK then you do not need the auto-generated the surrogate key so remove this and look at how to use composite ID class:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Composite_Primary_Keys

Answer (score 0):

You'll have use `@Embeddeble` and `@EmbeddedId` on class and specify pk columns. For more on it look [here](http://www.myeclipseide.com/PNphpBB2-viewtopic-t-11167.html)